# Super/Windows+L, what command does it use?

Tags: command-line

I am unable to discover what command is been output on the use of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key combination.

`gnome-screensaver-command -l` is not it, `dm-tool -lock` also not.

Does anybody know what it is?

Comment: What environment (OS, and window manager)?

Answer (score 2):

`dm-tool lock` works for me.

Note that there is no hyphen before lock

Comment: ➜  ~  dm-tool lock
Not running inside a display manager, XDG_SEAT_PATH not defined

Comment: That does NOT answer the question asked!!!
OP wanted information, now what worked for you.

Comment: @antofthy It could have worked, i pointed out a mistake in OP's command.